# Nokogiri isn't picking up direct descendant link tags in CSS selectors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, css-selectors, nokogiri

I'm using the Nokogiri gem in a Ruby on Rails app and running across a weird issue. Here's the HTML tree I'm dealing with:

[image]

Using Nokogiri on the parent HTML doc, I can successfully traverse the tree like this:

```
y[0].css("div.postContainer.opContainer div.post.op")[0]['id']
#  => "p25273352"

y[0].css("div.postContainer.opContainer div.post.op")[0].css(" > div").length
#  => 3

y[0].css("div.postContainer.opContainer div.post.op")[0].css(" > blockquote").length
#  => 1
```

However, when I attempt to do the same thing for the `a` or `span` tags, it can't find any direct descendants:

```
y[0].css("div.postContainer.opContainer div.post.op")[0].css(" > a").length
=> 0

y[0].css("div.postContainer.opContainer div.post.op")[0].css(" > span").length
#  => 0
```

Feel like I must be missing something obvious here but can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages, along with "[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/128421)"
and "[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812)". You're asking us to type in the HTML just to help you.

Comment: `css("div.postContainer.opContainer div.post.op")[0]` should be written using `at` or `at_css`. See https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html#single-results

Comment: It's difficult to help you without the smallest HTML in the question itself that demonstrates the problem. If the HTML is malformed Nokogiri will do a fixup, which can result in the HTML being changed. Check the `errors` method on the Nokogiri::HTML::Document  object after Nokogiri parsed the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're making it too hard.

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
  <div class="a b">
    <div></div>
    <span>foo</span>
    <a href="http://example.com/">bar</a>
  </div>
EOT
```

```
doc.at('div.a span').to_html   # => "<span>foo</span>"
doc.at('div.a a').to_html      # => "<a href=\"http://example.com/\">bar</a>"
```

or:

```
doc.at('div.a > span').to_html # => "<span>foo</span>"
doc.at('div.a > a').to_html    # => "<a href=\"http://example.com/\">bar</a>"
```

I'd access the child span/a nodes using [`at`](https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html#single-results) rather than `css("blah")[0]` or `css("blah").first`:

From the tutorial:

> If you know you're going to get only a single result back, you can use the shortcuts `at_css` and `at_xpath` instead of having to access the first element of a NodeSet.
>
> ```
> @doc.css("dramas name").first # => "<name>The A-Team</name>"
> @doc.at_css("dramas name")    # => "<name>The A-Team</name>"
> ```

`at` is the generic version of `at_css` and `at_xpath` and accepts either CSS or XPATH selectors.

There's a possibility the real HTML is mangled, which can cause problems locating a node when parsing. See the [`errors`](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Document.html#errors-instance_method) method. Never trust the browser's view of the HTML. Browsers will fix mangled HTML, basically rewriting it like Nokogiri will, but they might do it differently. Instead, always view your HTML using `wget`, `curl` or `nokogiri` at the command-line.

Answer (score -1):

> Feel like I must be missing something obvious here but can't figure it out. Any ideas?

JavaScript.

You have posted a screenshot from what looks like Chrome console. JavaScript runs in the browser and will modify DOM, potentially adding/removing HTML elements.

Your Ruby code most likely isn't running in Chrome though. Check the page source (Ctrl+U) or dump the response you are getting with your Ruby HTTP client and make sure that the elements you are trying to get with Nokogiri are actually there.

Comment: "most likely isn't running in Chrome..."? Ruby code can't run in a browser.

Comment: @theTinMan O'RLY? https://github.com/opal/opal (Also, some setup with headless Chrome could be possible, but whatever)

Comment: That's JavaScript, not Ruby running.

Comment: @theTinMan right, and JRuby is Java, not Ruby running?

Comment: The screenshot is of the Chrome inspector of the page that's being scraped by Nokogiri. It's not of the Rails/Nokogiri app.